# Call Generic Method System.Reflection.TargetException: Object does not match target type

Tags: c#, generics, dynamic, system.reflection

I'm trying to get an object based off of a string and id that are sent in.

```
var type = Type.GetType($"{Namespace.Models}.{typeName.Singularize().Pascalize()}");

MethodInfo method = typeof(IPreserver).GetMethod(nameof(IPreserver.ReadAsync));
MethodInfo generic = method.MakeGenericMethod(type);
var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
var model = generic.Invoke(instance, new object[] { id });
```

IPreserver is DI-ed into the controller. The signature of IPreserver.ReadAsync is:

```
Task<T> ReadAsync<T>(Guid id)
```

Everything looks good up to the `var model = generic.Invoke` line.  But then it throws:

```
System.Reflection.TargetException: Object does not match target type.
```

How can I properly call ReadAsync?

Comment: Surely you want the `ReadAsync` method of `type`?

Comment: I don't and don't call me Shirley.  But that helped.  I needed to pass in _preserver instead.  Thanks!

Comment: I appreciate your Airplane reference. I was telling my wife that she needs to watch that just last night :D I'm glad I could indirectly prompt you to solve it.